# Combine change Email Wordpress and woocommerce emails template

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kadence-woocommerce-email-designer/) plugin for customize woocommerce emails. But unfortunately I found out that it does not change the standard Core Wordpress emails. For example if client want change email in account details, website send a naked wordpress email template, and does not cling to the already created template for mails from this plugin. How to apply an already created template in this plugin, to all standard wordpress emails templates?

Comment: The plugin author says [they don't support that](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/does-not-change-reset-password-wordpress-email/) and you'd need a different plugin. Or are you asking how you'd go about developing that functionality yourself?

Comment: @Rup yes I would like to know if there is any solution in the role of writing a snippet that would apply a template for wordpress emails